# No symbols have been loaded for this document VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I have seen several posts regarding this same issue. None have solved my problem. I have recently downloaded VS2015, I had been using VS2012. I open the same project in both, 2015 does not load the symbols and 2012 does. If I open it in 2012 and build it, then open it in 2015 it will load the symbols until I rebuild it. Anyone have any ideas?

One other thing that I thought interesting. I have a Winforms app that I did the exact same process with and the Winforms app works great

Comment: Are the symbols part of another assembly? What is your main project?

Comment: There is only 1 project in the solution and that is the one it fails to load the symbols for.

Comment: What type of project is it? E.g., console, class library...

Comment: Windows Application, WPF Click once to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug with Telerik Data Access. They stopped supporting their visual designer. In order to fix the issue you have to get the updated Data Access from a NuGet package Telerik.DataAccess
The installation of the new data access should give you the Q2 2015 DLLs. It will also add a packages file to your project. You also need to open that and change the line

```
<UseXmlMapping Condition="'$(UseXmlMapping)'==''">false</UseXmlMapping>
to 

<UseXmlMapping Condition="'$(UseXmlMapping)'==''">true</UseXmlMapping>
```

And also add the following code at the end of your property groups and before item groups

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <UseXmlMapping>true</UseXmlMapping>
  </PropertyGroup>
```